# localhost refused to connect with jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

localhost refused to connect .
I have initialized this connection from cmd by write java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9191
but when I write http://localhost:9191/ give me this error

Comment: You question needs more clarity. What does your `java -jar` command give you in logs? Does it say that it's listening on port 9191? Currently it feels like nothing is listening on that port.

Comment: Can you please put the full error

Comment: Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

80b05f10cb6c46c187d36e0bc73d0262

This may also be found at: C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\secrets\initialAdminPassword

Comment: I was initialized jenkins server on my local machine